# Show that any $M\in\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{C})$ of rank $r$ can be written as $M = A N_r B$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

> Let $\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{C})$ be the set of all $n\times n$ matrices with entries in $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mbox{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$ denote the set of invertible $n\times n$ matrix in $\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{C})$. Show that any $M\in\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{C})$ of rank $r$ can be written as $$M=AN_rB,$$ where $A,B\in \mbox{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$ and
>
> $$N_r = \begin{bmatrix}
> 0 & I_r \\ 
> 0 &   0 \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I was thinking in use the "similarity" (i don't know the translate to english) of matrices, that is, $X$ and $Y$ are similar if there exists $P$ invertible such that $X=P^{−1}YP$. My idea is treat $X$ as $M$ and $Y$ as $N_r$, so $A$ and $B$ are $P^{−1}$ and $P$, respectivly (both are invertible as well). Sorry about my english, i believe you are brazilian too (because your name) haha. But i'm a little insecure about this idea to solve.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Can you perform elementary row/column operations on $M$ to transform it into $N_r$? That would mean you can find invertible matrices $P$ and $Q$ such that $PMQ = N_r$

Comment: Thanks, your hint help me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I get that!

**Solution**: Let $M \in \mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{C})$ such that $\mbox{rank}(M)=r>0$. Let $R$ be the **row-reduced echelon matrix** equivalent to $M$. So $R$ could be expressed by $$R=PM,$$ where $P$ is the product of elementary marices used to elementary operation in $M$. Since $R$ is an echelon matrix, we can operate in columns of $R$ until get $N_r$. In this case we say that $N_r$ is "column-equivalent" to $R$ and we have

$$N_r = R Q,$$

where $Q$ is the product of matrices "column-elementary". Via theorem, we have that elementary matrices are invertible, so its products as well, then $P,Q\in GL_n(\mathbb{C})$. Usying the equations above, we obtain

$$N_r=(PM)Q \implies P^{-1}N_r=MQ \implies P^{-1}N_rQ^{-1}=M.$$

Put $A \doteq P^{-1}$ and $B\doteq Q^{-1}$, then $$M=AN_rB,$$ with $A,B\in GL_n(\mathbb{C})$.